# Implementing Autocomplete for M2M Fields in Wagtail CustomUser Model

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have added two additional fields to my CustomUser model in my Wagtail project. These two fields are many-to-many (m2m) fields, and in the form, I want these fields to be represented as an Autocomplete feature. How can I achieve this?

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    journal = models.ManyToManyField("journal.Journal", verbose_name=_("Journal"), blank=True)
    collection = models.ManyToManyField("collection.Collection", verbose_name=_("Collection"), blank=True)
```

forms.py

```py
class CustomUserEditForm(UserEditForm):
    journal = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Journal.objects.all(), required=False, label=_("Journal"))
    collection = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Collection.objects.filter(is_active=True), required=True, label=_("Collection"))


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    journal = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Journal.objects.all(), required=False, label=_("Journal"))
    collection = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Collection.objects.filter(is_active=True), required=True, label=_("Collection"))
```

[image: my form]

Answer (score 0):

We use https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/

```
from dal import autocomplete

FieldPanel(
    'sponsors',
    heading='Event Sponsors',
    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
        url='master_calendar_public:event_sponsor_autocomplete',
        attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Search for Event Sponsors...', 'data-language': 'en'},
)
```

As you see you will need a view that does the autocomplete AJAX part.

```
class EventSponsorAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    # No pagination is necessary for these objects. There just aren't enough to matter, and a paginated <select> is a
    # pretty poor user experience.
    paginate_by = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = EventSponsor2.objects.all()

        # If the user has typed anything into the autocomplete widget, filter the queryset down to Sponsors that match.
        if self.q:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return queryset
```